# Please help me with my research title

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning-in-context, titles

I'm going to do a research with the title "The green effect in response to urban thermal environment". The content is about how vegetation can affect the temperature in the city. 
Is this title understandable and grammatically correct?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your suggested title would make me think the opposite of your explanation, i.e. that the temperature in the city can affect the vegetation.

Comment: Thank you. I intend to study the role of vegetation on reducing temperature in the city, so I used "in response to", but perhaps these words are confusing, so I will edit my title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about simply (and generally); "The Effects of Vegetation on Urban Environments"

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Does "the green effect" sound ok? In some researches, the term "urban effect" that increase the temperature is used, so I want to use "green effect" as an opposite effect that cools the environment.

Comment: I don't believe "the green effect" is in any type of common usage. If you pointedly want to use that phrase (as in coining a phrase), then it should be "explained" at the beginning of the article/paper - including in the Abstract or Executive summary.  Best,  JFC